# Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my react-redux application, i am trying to apply a set of style to a component based on some attributes. But when i load the application it complains with:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

Here is the root reducer:

```
import letterColor from './LetterColorReducer';

const root_reducer=combineReducers({
    letterColor:letterColor
});


export default root_reducer;
```

And here is the reducer function in the `LetterColorReducer` file:

```
export default function LetterColor(state={ color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal', fontWeight: 900 },action){

  switch(action.type){
  case 'Corrected_Typed':
    return { color:'green', fontWeight: 'normal', fontWeight: 900 };
  case 'Not_Corrected_Typed':
    return { color:'red',fontWeight: 'normal', fontWeight: 900 };
  case 'Active':
    return { color:'black', fontWeight: 'bold', fontWeight: 900 };
  default:
    return { color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal', fontWeight: 900 };
}
}
```

I have noticed that, **the error comes from the switch part**.
But i don't know what is wrong?

**Update**:

The component code is:

```
export default class Letter extends Component{

  render(){
    return(<div style={this.props.Styler()}>
                {this.props.value}
          </div>);
  }

}
```

the Styler() is just a simple action which ask for proper style from reducer.
Here is the `Styler()` code:

```
export default function(){


       console.log('Here is meeeeee');
         return {type:'Style',payload:''}; 
}
```

and here is the container code:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {newTypedLetter:state.newTypedLetter, letterColor:state.letterColor}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({Styler},dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Letter);
```

Comment: This problem should be about calling setState somewhere, not about your reducer.

Comment: Please provide your component code.

Comment: Looks like `Styler` dispatches actions to the store. You should not be calling those inside `render`. But you are calling it here: `<div style={this.props.Styler()}>` If you put the real code of `Styler` and explain what you are trying do with it someone might be able to help.

Comment: @ArunaHerath it's the exact code now

Answer (score 2):

First, your reducer is wrong.

A reducer gets passed all actions the app processes, including actions the reducer doesn't have anything to do with.

Also, whatever the reducer returns is going to be the state *from then on*. Be careful to think of the reducer as a way to *change the current state of the application* and not as some utility function that returns a value for you to use.

When you say

> just a simple action which ask for proper style from reducer

It seems to me you think that dispatching an action just calls the reducer and returns the value the reducer returns.

Neither are true. The value the reducer returns does not get returned by calling `Styler()`. The value returned by the reducer is the new state of the slice of the global app state the reducer manages.

If your reducer returns a new object even when an unknown action comes in (like your reducer does) then it will cause a number of big problems.

First, each time any action is dispatched anywhere in your app, your style will revert to the default style.

Second, because you return a new a object every time, anything `connect`ed to this part of the state will be rerendered. Again, this happens on any action at all, even unrelated ones.

Onwards.

From your code and your comments, it seems you're trying to use your reducer as a simple function which determines how to style your component.

Do not use a reducer for that. Use a simple function for that:

```
function letterColor(state){
  switch(state){
    case 'CORRECTED_TYPED':
      return { color:'green', fontWeight: 'normal' };
    case 'NOT_CORRECTED_TYPED':
      return { color:'red', fontWeight: 'normal' };
    case 'ACTIVE':
      return { color:'black', fontWeight: 'bold' };
    default:
      return { color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal' };
  }
}
```

The above function is not a reducer. You can use it like this:

```
export default class Letter extends Component{
  render(){
    return(<div style={letterColor('CORRECTED_TYPED')}>
                {this.props.value}
          </div>);
  }
}
```

I used the usual capitalization which is:

- normal functions start with a lower case and use camelCase
- constructor functions start with an upper case and use CamelCase
- constants and constant strings are entirely uppercase and use underscores

Redux is designed to manage state. State is the current situation in your app.

State changes over time as stuff happens. In Redux, this only happens when an action is dispatched.

Finding out what style to render something in does not change the state of your app. It should therfore not dispatch an action.

If a reducer doesn't know how to handle an action, it should always return the same state that it was called with.

If a reducer does not change the properties of an object in the state, it should always return the same object. If a reducer does not change the properties of a sub-object of the state, then it should always return the original sub-object as part of the new state.

State refers to the current situation in your app. It should not contain any data that you could find another way, for instance from a calculation based on other data in the state. This kind of data is called "derived data". The process of determining which data to store and which to derive is called [normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).